# How to understand the following brownian integral using Fubini's method?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, quantitative, quants

I am a little bit stucked with the following integral process, using Fubini's method, this is an intermediate step of short rate Merton Model.

$\int_{t}^{T} W(s)ds=\int_{0}^{\hat {T}}ds\int_{0}^{s}dW(u)\\=\int_{0}^{\hat {T}}dW(u)\int_{u}^{\hat {T}}ds\\=\int_{0}^{\hat {T}}(\hat{T}-u)dW(u)$

My more specific question is how did the change of integration variables proceed, as the process described by above integration is not very intuitive to me.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \int_0^T W(t)\, dt &{}= \int_0^T\!\!\int_0^t dW(u)\,dt \\ &{}= \int_0^T\!\!\int_u^T dt\, dW(u) \\&{}= \int_0^T (T - u)\,dW(u) \\&{}= TW(T) - \int_0^T u\, dW(u)
  \end{align*}

however i am not sure if it is what you are asking for

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However the second step is not clear for me, how did you change the integral variables from 0 - t with u to T? :D

Comment: @Donkey_JOHN It's easily seen on a graph with 2 axes: one for the integration variable $t $, say the vertical one, and one of the integration variable $u$, say the horizontal. You then see that the surface covered by all $t \in [0,T] $ and for each fixed $t$, $u \in [0,t] $ (i.e. the upper triangle on the graph) is the same as the one covered by all $u \in [0,T] $ and for each fixed $u $, $t \in [u, T] $. The first view corresponds to the first integral on the RHS, while the second reflects the second integral on the RHS. Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: @Quantuple Thanks for your explanation. I think I got what you mean, perfectly. Appreciated.

Comment: @Donkey_JOHN no problem. If the answer has helped you please consider accepting it. It might help others :)